# Can I create symbolic links with Nemo?

Tags: symlink, cinnamon, file-manager, nemo

I'm using the Nemo file manager (4.8.6) within the Cinnamon Desktop environment (4.8.6), on a Devuan Chimaera GNU/Linux system.

I would like to create a symbolic link to a file I have in my Nemo window. Can I do that?

- I can't copy then "paste link"
- I can't right-click the original and choose "Create symbolic link"
- I can't find a link-making facility on the main menus

So, is it really not there or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> + drag or

in nemo Select

```
Edit>Preferences>Context Menus and tick Make link
```

[image: context_menu]

Comment: "Make Link" kind of suggests it will be a hard link, but ok...

Comment: ok try it and ls for the inode?